# Should I use "laravelcollective/html": "5.2." instead of "illuminate/html" in my composer.json file going forward with Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravelcollective

The heading pretty much says it all, I'm just a bit concerned that "laravelcollective/html" might be deprecated in the future for another package.  Aren't there form helper methods that are build into the framework like in ASP.NET MVC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. `illuminate/html` was abandoned a year ago.

There are no form helpers in the core. `illuminate/html` was removed from the core and is now maintained by the LaravelCollective (`laravelcollective/html`).

Comment: Thanks for the comment @lagbox.